# how to embed a linux bash terminal inside ruby on rails web page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, linux

how to embed a bash prompt/terminal inside ruby on rails web page?

how to execute a linux command from the web page, and get the output of the ommand?

Comment: You are looking for an AJAX terminal. Several of them are mentioned in this [Stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944818/whats-a-good-browser-based-terminal-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

You must be looking for answers in this question: [Terminal on the web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715918/terminal-on-the-web-browser)

I myself found the right references there.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do that? :))

It's simple though, since ruby has `%x[]`

```
output = %x[#{input}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would probably be to take a preexisting [embeddable SSH implementation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=java%20applet%20ssh), such as a Java Applet, and include that in the page.